# How does one create EXTRA exact column widths in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that allows one to designate the width of columns in Excel in inches/centimeters using:

```
Application.InchesToPoints  
Application.CentimetersToPoints
```

The issue I'm having is that it is not that accurate. The results vary according to the font selected for the Normal Style.

For example, if I wish to designate the first 8 columns to be 1" wide, the macro will designate the columns to be 13 characters wide. When the Normal Style is Calibri 10 pt, the width should be at least 13.43 characters wide. When the Normal Style is Century Gothic 10 pt, the width should be equal to or greater 12.29 characters wide.

(I have a similar macro for row height. That isn't that accurate either.)

Questions:

1. Are `Application.InchesToPoints` and `Application.CentimetersToPoints` relative to a specific default font?
2. What is that font?
3. Is there a way to correct the macro so it more accurately designates columns in inches?

The macro I am using is provided below.

```
Sub SetColumnWidthInInches()
' This macro sets widths of rows in inches

    Dim Inches As Double, points As Double, savewidth As Double
    Dim lowerwidth As Double, upwidth As Double, curwidth As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Inches = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Width in Inches", _
    "Column Width (Inches)", Type:=1)

    If Inches = False Then Exit Sub

    points = Application.InchesToPoints(Inches)
    savewidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
    ActiveCell.ColumnWidth = 255

    If points > ActiveCell.Width Then
        MsgBox "Width of " & Inches & " is too large." & Chr(10) & _
            "The maximum value is " & _
            Format(ActiveCell.Width / 28.3464566929134, _
            "0.00"), vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Width Error"
        ActiveCell.ColumnWidth = savewidth
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lowerwidth = 0
    upwidth = 255
    ActiveCell.ColumnWidth = 127.5
    curwidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
    Count = 0

    While (ActiveCell.Width <> points) And (Count < 20)
        If ActiveCell.Width < points Then
            lowerwidth = curwidth
            Selection.ColumnWidth = (curwidth + upwidth) / 2
        Else
            upwidth = curwidth
            Selection.ColumnWidth = (curwidth + lowerwidth) / 2
        End If
        curwidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
        Count = Count + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Checked here? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214123/description-of-how-column-widths-are-determined-in-excel

Comment: There are different methods of achieving "exact" dimensions depending on whether you're talking about **screen measurements** or **printed dimensions**. It's not straightforward because Excel isn't graphics software.  Related: [MS Support: **The column width is not the same when printed in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214394/the-column-width-is-not-the-same-when-printed-in-excel), and: [SuperUser: **How to make cells perfect squares in Excel?**](https://superuser.com/questions/165738/how-to-make-cells-perfect-squares-in-excel). Also, stick with monospace fonts for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I decided to create my own Application.InchesToPoints "formula" rather than use Microsoft's. Each font required a unique formula. It's still not exact due to Microsoft's column- and row-size rounding, but my formula is close.

I like all my spreadsheets to be identically sized and fill the space between margins. So, I wrote a second macro that "ratchets" the size of one column and row up or down so the entire page is filled to make up for the rounding issue.

**To set the row height, I wrote this**:

Sub SetRowHeightInInches()
'
' This macro sets heights of rows
' in inches for certain fonts

'

Dim Inches As Double, Points As Double, Slope As Double, Constant As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (10) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 74.222
    Constant = -0.0788
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 70.1009
    Constant = -0.0735
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 74.906
    Constant = -0.0588
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 73.0763
    Constant = -0.0704
End If
```

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (9) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 77.3051
    Constant = -0.0791
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 72.6606
    Constant = -0.0568
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 86.2616
    Constant = -0.0727
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 78.7424
    Constant = -0.0695
End If
```

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (8) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 79.303
    Constant = -0.0759
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 74.9169
    Constant = -0.1002
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 88.8749
    Constant = -0.0216
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 81.0316
    Constant = -0.0659
End If
```

End If

```
Inches = Application.InputBox("Enter Row Height in Inches", _
"Row Height (Inches)", Type:=1)

If Inches Then

    Points = Inches * Slope + Constant
    Selection.RowHeight = Points

End If
```

End Sub

**To set the column width, I wrote this:**

Sub SetColWidthInInches()
'
' This macro sets widths of columns
' in inches for certain fonts

'

Dim Inches As Double, Points As Double, Slope As Double, Constant As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (10) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 13.0253
    Constant = -0.7805
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 14.2722
    Constant = -0.7976
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 13.0314
    Constant = -0.7946
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 13.3214
    Constant = -0.7946
End If
```

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (9) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 14.2722
    Constant = -0.7976
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 15.7747
    Constant = -0.902
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 14.2747
    Constant = -0.7961
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 14.2747
    Constant = -0.7976
End If
```

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Size = (8) Then

```
If ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Arial" Then
    Slope = 16.2077
    Constant = -0.9478
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
    Slope = 17.6073
    Constant = -0.9255
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Century Gothic" Then
    Slope = 16.2077
    Constant = -0.9478
Else
    MsgBox "The normal font for this workbook is not 8-10 pt Arial, Calibri or Century Gothic. This macro will yield an approximation."
    Slope = 16.2077
    Constant = -0.9478
End If
```

End If

```
Inches = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Width in Inches", _
"Column Width (Inches)", Type:=1)

If Inches Then

    Points = Inches * Slope + Constant
    Selection.ColumnWidth = Points

End If
```

End Sub

**To fill the page I wrote this:**

Sub AutoFitColumn()
'
' Changes Column Size
' To fill worksheet

'

Dim Size As Single
Size = Selection.ColumnWidth
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count = 0 Then

```
Do
  Size = Size + 0.2
  Selection.ColumnWidth = Size
Loop Until ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count = 1
End If
```

If ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then

```
Do
  Size = Size - 0.1
  Selection.ColumnWidth = Size
Loop Until ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count = 0
End If
```

Range("A1").Select

End Sub

**and this**

Sub AutoFitRow()
'
' Changes Row Size
' To fill worksheet

'

Dim Size As Single
Size = Selection.RowHeight
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
If ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count = 0 Then

Do
  Size = Size + 0.5
  Selection.RowHeight = Size
Loop Until ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count = 1
End If
```

If ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then

```
Do
  Size = Size - 0.25
  Selection.RowHeight = Size
Loop Until ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count = 0
End If
```

Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Comment: Edit your post. Select all of the code (from top to bottom), and then either hit Ctrl+K on the keyboard or the `{}` toolbar button to format it as code. (I could edit to do it for you, but then you wouldn't know how to post it next time.)